# Is the description for "not constructive" appropriate?

Tags: discussion, support, not-constructive

Two years ago I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894912/confusion-regarding-patricia) with the intent of clarifying the definition of a term. It's worth noting that the term in question does have a precise definition which I later found from a highly reputable resource, and presented in my answer (which I then accepted, of course). The question was then closed as "not constructive".

The explanation for the reason it was closed seems confusing to me. That is:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

Why isn't this question a good fit for SOs Q&A format? Are questions requesting clarification, which can be answered using highly reputable resources, inappropriate? That seems to be a *huge percentage* of SO questions that should now be closed, but aren't and won't be, even if I flag or vote to close them.

Isn't the original resource defining a term considered to be highly reputable? Don't papers from the journal of ACM count as references?

Are people likely to debate the accepted answer, despite the highly reputable citations that it uses? I would expect such a debate to come up with equally reputable citations for support, which is quite unlikely, but I'd like to allow it anyway...

Is that kind of debate really considered to be "not constructive"? What if the debate is healthy (due to respectful language and structure) and conclusive (due to presence of ultimate authoritarian resources)?

Comment: Would not the approach be to try to bring this to the attention of someone able to vote to re-open the question, via a comment or flag on the question? (rather than asking a meta question)

Comment: @David I have voted to reopen the question, unsuccessfully, numerous times... Quite recently, in fact. That's not the aim of this question. The aim of this question is to question the description. It is clear that it won't be reopened and is somehow *not constructive*, in spite of contradictions in the description. I'm asking for a review of the description for *not constructive*.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: That is an old close reason for shopping questions, comparison of product and stuffs along that line. Putting the close reason aside, I think your question looks fine, so I have voted to reopen.

Comment: "Not constructive" no longer exists so this isn't going to be a useful discussion at all...

Comment: @Ben: It still exists - the post notice is clearly there on all posts that were previously closed with it. Sure, any amount of discussion isn't going to effect a change now that the close reason is no longer in use, but you can't expect people to just ignore the reason or something when it is *there* and it is preventing the question from being answered. Or maybe if we reopened every post that was closed as NC...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour I have gotten this question [unlocked. Discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299727/1768232)

Answer (score 2):

The **not constructive** close reason no longer exists. It's still off-topic however, as it doesn't address a specific *practical* problem with programming - it's much more computer science/theory/whiteboard related.

Anyway, I'll give a go at reasons I can see it was closed (and has been voted to be left closed by the community twice in the reopen queue):

Let's start with the closing statement of your question (emphasis mine):

> I guess I'm concerned about the accuracy of my resources (edit: ... and these aren't the only two references in dispute on this topic). **Which of these references are correct**?

Then the start of Ivaylo Strandjev's answer (emphasis mine):

> Although both definitions seem to be correct, first one is more detailed **and seems better to me**

Now, let's switch to your answer (emphasis mine):

> Though Ivaylo Strandjev's answer does seem to be the common definition, **I believe that common definition hasn't done justice by blurring the definition** of PATRICIA. After all, there are already umbrella terms for this common definition. 
> [...] 
> In conclusion, there's a *common, obscure definition* which seems to have become a synonym for "radix trie" (and perhaps in some cases eg. libstdc++, "multi-way radix trie"), and a *specific, original definition* which deviates from the *common definition* quite significantly.

Does that even answer your own question? Which reference is correct - none, one or both...?

The post even spilled over into [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/27861/2013/4/9) - where you also posted:

> Well, ultimately it's misleading that there are so many contradictory definitions of something that was initially meant to be a specific term.

It looks like the moderator who closed the question agreed with a flag that was made on the post - which probably sums it up nicely:

> At first, this may seem like an objective, factually answerable question, but it's really an argument about what constitutes a data structure between two authors. There is not going to be a "correct" answer that is generally useful to others

Comment: The [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) advises that "if your question generally covers… a software algorithm, ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!". Is this not a question regarding a software algorithm?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour you're asking for the "correct" technical definition of  a data structure - that's different than using/implementing an algorithm...

Comment: It is most certainly a prerequisite to using/implementing the algorithm. If I were asked to implement PATRICIA in college, and I implemented the wrong algorithm (simply because it's *the common definition* rather than *the correct definition*), I would fail that assessment.

Comment: However, I'd assume college would tell you *which definition* they wanted. It's just your opinion that Morrison's definition is the *correct* one. Perhaps what's considered *correct* is the *common definition* and if you were to implement what you consider *correct* - you'd be wrong. It's handy to know the way different people define Particia, but at the end of the day - what's *correct* will depend on *context* and what people think.

Comment: I doubt any reputable college would work that way. They can't *say* they're teaching one thing (e.g. C) and then actually teach something completely different (e.g. Javascript). [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator) is asking for *the "correct" technical definition* of an operator, which is different from using/implementing an operator. Shouldn't it be closed? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) fits one of the reasons for off-topic closure precisely.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour the later question is from 2008 - it's one of those - yes it's off-topic now, but was acceptable at the time kind of the question... it still may be of some use. Let's focus on the post you're addressing - comparing to other posts from different eras etc... will only lead to wasted time and madness :)

Comment: Very well. *"Which reference is correct - none, one or both...?"* That first paragraph from my answer, and the conclusion, which forms your entire quote, aren't necessary parts of my answer. If you remove them, the meaning of my answer won't change significantly. Again, I doubt any reputable college would disagree with this; three of the sources I used come from highly reputable professors: Morrison, Sedgewick and Knuth. Colleges generally wouldn't, however, permit Wikipedia citations (which the other answer relies solely upon). Which one is correct at college? The answer is obvious.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a response here, Jon...