# Why was my flag declined on unlocking a rejected migration?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, declined-flags, meta, reopen-closed

This question was closed recently: [Is the description for "not constructive" appropriate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299341/1768232)

Because it was migrated from MSE, it was automatically locked as per rejected migration rules. I wanted to vote to reopen, but could not because it was locked. So I made a custom flag:

> I don't agree with the closure; I am not asking for this to be reopened, simply that we ought to be able to vote to do so.

My flag was declined:

> declined - Your disagreement is noted. You don't need to notify moderators that you disagree, you can just disagree without notification next time.

I can't vote to reopen a locked post without moderator involvement. In fact, I *do* need to notify moderators that I disagree. I didn't want to flag for a unilateral unlock, because I don't think that question is something that *so blatantly* should be reopened that I want to see a unilateral unlock, but I did want to put my reopen vote on it and see if there were four other members of the community that agreed with me.

Related: [Don't treat closed questions on meta as rejected migrations from main](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299599/1768232)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wasn't the moderator who declined this, but I can see why they missed what you were trying to point out. As you stated, the entirety of your flag was

> I don't agree with the closure; I am not asking for this to be
>   reopened, simply that we ought to be able to vote to do so.

Nowhere in there did you explicitly state that the question was locked, and you didn't tell us that we needed to unlock that post. When I look at the question, it doesn't state that it's locked (in fact, it [currently shows in the timeline that the post is unlocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/260714/revisions)). The wording of your flag at first makes it seem that you just want to state that it shouldn't have been closed.

Moderators can still vote on locked posts, so we wouldn't notice that normal users couldn't. It's easy for us to forget that failed migrations can lead to locks on posts. As I point out above, the history seems to show that the post *was* unlocked on the failed migration. Therefore, you'll want to be clear in your flag that the post was locked and that you wanted us to unlock it.

Comment: I thought that "we ought to be able to do so" implies that we can't, which means the question is locked; I'll try to be more clear in the future. Also, while the MSE version of the question might not be locked, the MSO version is definitely still locked.

Comment: @durron597 - You're right, that's the Meta.SE side of it. Rejected migrations get to be a mess sometimes, so it's hard to tell what you're looking at. I've manually unlocked the Meta.SO side of that now.

Comment: @durron597: Sorry, we can't reverse a declined flag.